# how to install package requirements gtk+-3.0 >= 3.9.10, glib-2.0 >= 2.37.5 and gio-2.0 >= 2.30.0

Tags: package-management, compiling, gtk3

I am trying to compile [Disk Usage Analyzer](https://git.gnome.org/browse/baobab). In preparing to compile, I am informed of certain requirements that are not present:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (
    gtk+-3.0 >= 3.9.10
    glib-2.0 >= 2.37.5
    gio-2.0 >= 2.30.0
) were not met:

Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.9.10' but version of GTK+ is 3.8.4
```

Could you point me in the right direction on how to install these prerequisites? Thanks!